# AEM 6.1 switching between preview and edit mode without refresh

Tags: aem, sightly

Is it possible to update the view on AEM between Edit and Preview Mode without having to refresh?

Maybe we are targetting the issue from the wrong angle but basically we need to modify the way components are being displayed on Edit Mode vs Preview Mode. Currently if we use a test statement to check what WCMMODE we are looking at we need to refresh the page in order for the right content to display.

I have the feeling that I have seen this being implemented in GeoMetrixx but I am not able to find an example.

Comment: Can you clarify the problem you are having?  By default switching between edit mode and preview mode does not trigger a refresh, so if it is refreshing now it is, because it has been customized.  It sounds like your issue is more related to custom code rendering components differently between modes.

Comment: From my experience, the page is not refreshed and WCMMODE is not changed until you refresh the page, I suggest that you keep refreshing the page for now and open a ticket with daycare. I did already but no success!

Comment: @PaulMichelotti, You are correct, there is no need for a refresh switching between modes. However there are some instances that in order for a component to be rendered properly part of a script needs to be executed which may need to know what mode you are in. Again, we may need to revisit how the components are being created but that is currently our issue.